# Oven broil element use as oven bake element?

Tags: electrical, oven

Bake element is bad I have a spare broil element with the same width and connections as the bake element. Can I replace it with the broil element?

Comment: Give us the make and model number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to physical connections there is the key issue of how much heat is produced. With a simple resistance element, this can be tested using a multimeter to check resistance.

For example, I found a [GE-compatible broil element on Amazon](https://amzn.to/45FYVmD) that is rated at 3410 W:

[image: GE broil]

(Oops, 3410 W rating is from another site, but Amazon makes it easier to add pictures.)

[Ohm's law](https://ohmslawcalculator.com/ohms-law-calculator) says this should be ~ 16.9 Ohms.

So the key is to find out the correct rating of your broil and bake elements and compare. Unfortunately, if your old element is electrically broken it will likely show no continuity/infinite Ohms, so the real comparison is going to be based on manufacturer specs. You don't actually have to check the resistance on a new element. Just the rated Wattage. If the bake is 3000W and the broil is 4000W, or vice versa, then this may not be a good idea. If they are the same and the element fits, use it. If the replacement that you have on hand is *smaller* (in terms of Watts) then it is probably *safe* to use, but it won't be as effective as the correct element. If the replacement is larger then I do **not recommend** using it as the oven may not be designed to handle that amount of heat in that location.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the make and model, they can be interchangeable.

Look closely on the elements close to the power connections for a part number.

If part numbers are the same for the non working bake and the new broil element then obviously they can be swapped, as they are the same.

If numbers aren't the same, but the elements are a match physically, there should be no issue with using the broil element for the bake function if needed for an emergency. ( big family dinner planned) The temperature may be different and cooking times may have to be adjusted as the broil element may heat differently.

I would want to get the proper bake element ASAP.